# How do I add a pagination on a template file?

Tags: 8, paging

I'm currently new with Drupal 8 and right now I'm trying to output a pagination on my twig file using entity query. So far this is my current code that I came up with. My goal is output the news content type using entity and add a pagination. I've already added `pager(9)` to display only 9 items. I tried inserting `{{pager}}` on my twig file but I don't see any pagination being rendered. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Really need some help.

```
// Entity Query for News
//////////////////////////////////////////////////


$newsPostings = $query->get('node')
    ->condition('status', 1, '=')
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->sort('created', 'desc')
    ->pager(9)
    ->execute();

foreach ($newsPostings as $key => $news_postings) {

    $newsNode = _nodeLoad($news_postings);


    $publishDate = strtotime($newsNode->get('created')->value);
    $articleCreated = date('F j, Y', $publishDate);


    $variables['article'][$key]['title'] = $newsNode->get('title')->value;
    $variables['article'][$key]['image'] = $newsNode->field_image->entity->url();
    $variables['article'][$key]['path'] = $newsNode->toUrl();
    $variables['article'][$key]['date'] = $articleCreated;
}

// Pager for News Entity Query
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
$nodesNews =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($newsPostings);
$pathNews = base_path();

$pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(9);
$result = $pager->execute();

 $build['results'] = array(
     '#theme' => 'page__news',
     '#items' => $nodesNews,
     '#path'  => $pathNews,
   );

   $build['pager'] = array(
     '#type' => 'pager'
   );


return $build;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to add pager,for the pagination we need to extend the pagerselectextender and add limit in the query.

```
 $pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(9);
 $result = $pager->execute();


/////////////////updated////////////////////
     $query->get('node')
     $query->condition('status', 1, '=')
     $query->condition('type', 'article')
     $query->sort('created', 'desc')
     $pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(1);
     $newsPostings = $pager->execute();
////////////////////updated///////////////////////////


  $build['results'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'page__news',
      '#items' => $nodesNews,
      '#path'  => $pathNews,
    );

    $build['pager'] = array(
      '#type' => 'pager'
    );
```

Comment: I think I've tried this before, tried it again it comes out empty :(

Comment: Really not sure which part I'm currently getting it wrong :(

Comment: Right now it gives me this error `Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryFactory::extend() in aim_preprocess_page()` basically it is pointing to this line `$pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(9);`

Comment: Your d8 version? Could you please paste the modified query?

Comment: Updated my question with the updated code you requested and yes I'm using Drupal 8

Comment: Here variable $query is not used in your query,  use $newsPostings instead of $query.Also remove ->pager(9) ->execute();

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, if I were to remove `->pager(9)` and `->execute()` how I can output the content? I've updated my question modified it with your answer. Still getting an error `Call to a member function get() on null in aim_preprocess_page()`

Comment: Updated query.pls check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66859/discussion-between-clestcruz-and-sarika).

Answer (score 0):

Use the render service either via dependency injection or directly from service container.

```
$pager = array(
      '#type' => 'pager'
    );

$build['results'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'page__news',
      '#items' => $nodesNews,
      '#path'  => $pathNews,
      '#pager' => \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($pager)
    );
```

Then print **{{ pager }}** into your twig file.